# problem with livewire and arrays when trying to print to pdf

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm having a problem with Livewire passing an array to a route so I can print it to pdf. I've got:

```
public $selectedProducts = [];
public $selectedAlm = [];
public $nombreComponente, $data, $categoriaId;

public function mount()
{
    $this->categoriaId = "0";
    $this->nombreComponente = 'Reportes';
    $this->data = [];
    $this->artcero = 'si';
}
```

where $selectedProducts and $selectedAlm are arrays and my intention is to pass them to another controller to be able to print them to pdf, but I can't seem to find a way

here is my controller:

```
    public function reportearticuloPDF($categoriaId, $artcero, $selectedAlm, $selectedProducts)
{
    if ($selectedProducts > 0) {
        $data = $selectedProducts;
        
    } else {
        if ($categoriaId == null) {
            $data = Articulo::join('categorias as c', 'c.id', 'articulos.categoria_id')
            ->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom')
            ->whereHas('detallearticulos', function($q) {
    
                $q->whereIn('almacen_id', $selectedAlm);
            
            })
            ->when($artcero == 'no', function($query){
                return $query->where('stock', '>', 0);
            })
            ->OrderBy('id', 'ASC')
            ->get();
        } elseif ($categoriaId !== null) {
            $data = Articulo::join('categorias as c', 'c.id', 'articulos.categoria_id')
            ->select('articulos.*', 'c.nombre as catnom')
            ->whereHas('detallearticulos', function($q) {
    
                $q->whereIn('almacen_id', $selectedAlm);
     

   
        })->with('detallearticulos')
        ->when($artcero == 'no', function($query){
            return $query->where('stock', '>', 0);
        })
        ->where('categoria_id', $categoriaId)
        ->OrderBy('id', 'ASC')
        ->get();
    }
}

$pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.report.articulopdf', compact('data'));
    return $pdf->stream('Reporte_de_articulo.pdf');
```

}

my routes in web.php:

```
    Route::get('report/articulopdf/{categoriaId}/{artcero}/{selectedAlm}/{selectedProducts}', [ReportController::class, 'reportearticuloPDF'])->name('reportearticulo.pdf');
Route::get('report/articulopdf/{categoriaId}/{artcero}/{selectedAlm}', [ReportController::class, 'reportearticuloPDF'])->name('reportearticulo.pdf');
```

my button:

```
 <a href="{{ url('report/articulopdf' . '/' . $categoriaId . '/' . $artcero . '/' . $selectedAlm . '/' . $selectedProducts) }}" 
class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block {{ count($data) < 1 ? 'disabled' : '' }}" target="_blank">
Exportar reporte a PDF <i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i></a>
```

that's the one that gives me the `Array to string conversion` error. I also tried it this way:

```
    <a href="{{ route('reportearticuloPDF', $categoriaId, $artcero, $selectedAlm, $selectedProducts) }}"
class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block {{ count($data) < 1 ? 'disabled' : '' }}" target="_blank">
Exportar reporte a PDF <i class="fas fa-file-pdf"></i></a>
```

but it gives me the error `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ReportController::reportearticuloPDF(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistemainventarioGDS\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 4 expected`

Answer (score 0):

In your routes you create two routes with the same method  and same function `reportearticuloPDF` in the controller with different params !!